# My Bootstrap Window Became to large?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When I refreshed my browser something made my windows almost twice as large now everything is awkwardly placed. Not sure what I did?

Comment: Some code would help.

Comment: Even the best of us are not clairvoyant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may have zoomed in on you're current website and have not specified how the div's should act as of yet.

```
<div class="col-xs-12"> //Stuff here etc </div>
```

The above div will display well across all sizes, but obviously you should assign all screen sizes (xs, sm, md and lg). If you could update you're question with more information that would help greatly.

Comment: Thank You! I'm new to this so I was just testing a question out.

Comment: That's okay Cameron, Though for future reference read the help material provided before posting a question or people are likely to throw pitchforks at you :-).